# angular-froala 2.1.0 data-binding not working with angular 1.1.5

Tags: angularjs, froala

I'm currently working on a project using Angular 1.1.5.
Upgrading Angular is not an option for now.

We would like to implement a rich HTML5 WYSIWYG-editor and dicided to give Froala a try, as it meets our requirements and the [docs](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/blob/master/bower.json) of angular-froala state that it should work with all versions of Angular >=1.0 .

I have made a POC on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BWgcst) that uses Angular 1.1.5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Font Awesome. -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-3dkvEK0WLHRJ7/Csr0BZjAWxERc5WH7bdeUya2aXxdU= sha512-+L4yy6FRcDGbXJ9mPG8MT/3UCDzwR9gPeyFNMCtInsol++5m3bk2bXWKdZjvybmohrAsn3Ua5x8gfLnbE1YkOg=="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Include Froala Editor styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/froala_editor.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/froala_style.min.css" />

  <!-- Include Froala Editor Plugins styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/char_counter.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/code_view.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/colors.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/emoticons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/file.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/fullscreen.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/image_manager.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/image.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/line_breaker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/table.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/css/plugins/video.css">

  <!-- Include Froala Editor -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Froala Editor Plugins -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/align.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/char_counter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/code_beautifier.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/code_view.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/colors.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/emoticons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/entities.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/file.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/font_family.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/font_size.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/fullscreen.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/image.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/image_manager.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/inline_style.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/line_breaker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/link.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/lists.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/paragraph_format.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/paragraph_style.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/quote.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/save.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/plugins/video.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End Froala -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="angular-froala.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->

<body ng-controller="mainController">

  <div class="sample">
    <h2>Sample 2: Full Editor</h2>
    <textarea id="froala-sample-2" froala ng-model="sample2Text"></textarea>
    <h4>HTML Content:</h4> {{sample2Text}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

everything seems to work fine except the most important part, the data-binding.
Upgrading the Angular version to 1.5.0 fixes the issue in the POC. But as mentioned that is not an option in my case.

Is this a bug? Is the documentation of froala-angular outdated? 
Is there some kind of workaround besides upgrading Angular?
Or am I simply missing something here?

Comment: What did you tried already? Have you debugged the Froala directive?

Comment: I tried multiple Angular versions and noticed that the same problem occured till angular 1.2.29
The binding starts working from Angular 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with this version of Angular when trying to use ngModel in a directive.

> https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924
>
> When ngModel directive is used on an element that represents a component (implemented via a directive with isolate scope), ngModel is locked into this isolate scope and in order to get out and make ngModel useful the ngModel expression has to be prefixed with $parent.

As suggested in this thread I tried using the $parent prefix and could notice one way data-binding finding place.

```
<textarea id="froala-sample-2" froala ng-model="$parent.sample2Text"></textarea>
```

To get my model to be updated, I had to call $apply() in the froala-directive which forces a $digest().

```
ctrl.updateModelView = function () {
    var returnedHtml = element.froalaEditor('html.get');
    if (angular.isString(returnedHtml)) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(returnedHtml);
        })
    }
};
```

I updated my POC on plunker for those who want to see it running.

Comment: Can you please edit your plunker to tell me how to add few more options to toolbar in froala? followed its documentation, but it won't work. I was trying to add more *toolbarButtons* to it, like `align, formatOL, formatUL` by including their plugins. Still didn't work. [link to toolbarbuttons](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but for anyone looking for a solution, I fixed the issue by changing from:

```
<textarea froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="myHtml"></textarea>
```

to this:

```
<textarea froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="$parent.myHtml"></textarea>
```